# How to stop WordPress from replacing plus (+) characters from URL on the front page?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a website that is sort of e-commerce website. The list of products is on the homepage. On the left side is a sidebar where you can filter products. Once 2 filters of one category are selected you will get a link that looks like this **yourdomain/?_category=item1+item2**. The problem is that once you reload the page or if you want to share that link with someone, it becomes like that: **yourdomain/?_category=item1`%20`item2**. Plus sign is gone and there is `%20` instead. What makes it even more interesting is that it happens only on the homepage. As soon as the page is not set to be a front page, it works well.

The same happens here: https://wordpress.org/?query=test+string

Here it works fine: https://wordpress.org/download/?query=test+hello

Comment: URL special characters are encoded by default and you can not avoid this.

Comment: Thank you @Gregory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late reply, but this should allow such query strings on the homepage...

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','disable_frontpage_canonical_redirect');
function disable_frontpage_canonical_redirect($redirect)
{
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $redirect = false;
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you :)